# Identifying the value of parameters of the prior distribution. Arbitrarily?

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution, conjugate-prior

Referring to this [Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/583849/is-using-an-aproximation-technique-to-estimate-the-parameter-under-a-known-poste), let's not use Jeffrey's prior for $\theta$ but use $Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ as the conjugate prior for $\theta$. Under quadratic loss function, the bayes estimator for $\theta$ is
$$
\tilde{\theta}_{Bayes}=\frac{\beta(\alpha+\sum_{i=1}^{n} {x_i})}{1+n\beta}.
$$

As opposed to the estimator in the [Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/583849/is-using-an-aproximation-technique-to-estimate-the-parameter-under-a-known-poste), this Bayes estimator depends on the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. If I were to further estimate $(\alpha,\beta)$, this will lead to hierarchical Bayesian, right? I am not interested yet in hierarchical Bayesian.

Ultimately, my question is for simulation study, say after generating data from Poisson distribution, I would like to see if $\tilde{\theta}_{Bayes}$ perform adequately with comparison to $\hat{\theta}_{mle}$, should I arbitrarily choose several pair values of $(\alpha,\beta)$ and compares the $\tilde{\theta}_{Bayes}$ with true $\theta$?

Comment: Subjectively rather than arbitrarily!

Comment: If you estimated the hyperparameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from the data then you would doing what is known as ``empirical Bayes''. (Hierarchical Bayes is something different.) Empirical Bayes is really only applicable if you have samples from several Poisson distributions, not just one.

Comment: I see. So, if I were not using empirical Bayes method, can I arbitrarily set the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for simulation and real data application. Because usually the prior parameters are fixed but I am unsure how to go about it.

Comment: Choosing parameters arbitrarily is obviously meaningless as it will just produce arbitrary resuts. Your questions so far don't entirely make sense. I suggest that you try to describe what the real scientific problem is that you are trying to solve instead of asking an artificial question. What is the real data? I wonder whether you are actually doing Bayes are at all or simply trying to define an over-dispersed Poisson distribution. A gamma-Poisson mixture is simply negative binomial.

Comment: @GordonSmyth the data is simulated from $Pois(\theta)$ (actually from some type of inflated Poisson but for simplicity, let's keep it as $Pois(\theta)$). And I would like to compare if MLE or Bayes estimator performed better. Both MLE and Bayes estimator provided different estimators. However, the Bayes estimator relies on $\alpha,\beta$. But for simulation study, I do not know what is the values of $\alpha,\beta$. If we're using Jeffrey's prior, $\alpha=1/2,\beta \to \infty$. But for conjugate prior, the $\alpha,\beta$ are supposed to be fixed (I think) but I don't know what values to choose.

Comment: You've ignored my suggestion to give the real context and instead have just summarized the same question again, so there is no way for me to help you. You don't actually have a Bayes prior so there is nothing to compare. If you did have a Bayes prior, then the results would be known analytically so there would be no need for a simulation.

Comment: I did provide the Bayes prior in the question which is $\theta\sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$. I am comparing MLE with Bayes estimator (Quadratic Loss Function) using simulated data. So, there is no real data. The posterior was described in the previous question (using Jeffrey's prior), linked.

Comment: A Bayesian prior contains no unknown parameters. You don't know $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you don't even have subjective guesses, so therefore you have no prior.

Comment: The use of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is to show the general form of the prior. Allow me to say that this is related to a paper I would like to publish. So, in the paper, I write down the general form first. Later, for simulation study, I have to fix their values (subjective guesses). But I cannot simply select the values without a reasonable assumption (which I dont have yet). I wonder how can I guess the values of the parameters.